# Is there an equilibruim in an unsaturated calcium hydroxide solution?

Tags: equilibrium

Imagine an unsaturated(No Ca(OH)<sub>2</sub> <sub>(s)</sub> just Ca<sup>2+</sup> <sub>(aq)</sub> and OH<sup>-</sup> <sub>(aq)</sub>)  aqueous solution of Calcium Hydroxide.

Is the following equilibrium present in that solution and does the transparency of an unsaturated Calcium Hydroxide vanish after a while?

$$\ce{ Ca^2+_{(aq)} + 2OH- _{(aq)} <=>  Ca(OH)2_{(s)}}$$

Comment: No and no (well, in real world the solution might get cloudy, but that's for entirely unrelated reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equilibria in solutions are given as solubility products, $K_{\text{sp}}$. Your reaction is:

$$\ce{Ca(OH)_2 <=> Ca^2+ + 2OH-}$$
for this, $K_{\text{sp}}=5.5\times 10^{-6}$ (from Wikipedia). What this means, is that in a *saturated solution*, at equilibrium, you will have:
$$K_{\text{sp}}=[\ce{Ca^2+}]  [\ce{OH-}]^2=5.5\times10^{-6}$$

However, for an *unsaturated* solution, you will have:

$$[\ce{Ca^2+}]  [\ce{OH-}]^2 <K_{\text{sp}}$$

As mentioned the solution does get cloudy for different reasons, namely the formation of $\ce{CaCO3}$ by reaction with $\ce{CO2}$.